# To write to another text file by appending the data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$myFile = APPPATH.'/../log.txt';
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "New Stuff 1\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "New Stuff 2\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Above shown is my code.
**output** :

```
New Stuff 1New Stuff 2
```

I need New Stuff 2 in the second line

Also the newly written data should append to the existing data.How to fix the issue.

Comment: It's already being appended. As for the newline, try `\r\n`, are you on windows?

Comment: I need New Stuff 2 in the next line.

Comment: @user3135796: Use `PHP_EOL` instead.

Comment: What **output** are you talking about? To the browser? To the file? And how exactly did you determine, that the output is `New Stuff 1New Stuff 2 `?

Comment: You're overwriting the variable the second time. In any case, `echo $stringData;` at the end of the code would **not** produce the output provided in your question. You need to change `$stringData = "New Stuff 2\n"`, to `$stringData .= "New Stuff 2\n"`. (`.=` is used for appending strings)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use PHP Predefined Constant `PHP_EOL`

```
$stringData = "New Stuff 1" . PHP_EOL;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "New Stuff 2" . PHP_EOL;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
```

it will produce `\r\n`

Comment: Now what is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score -1):

`file_put_content('your.txt',"data\n". PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);`

try this.by the way if you open file in browser will will not show you next line with `"\n"` try to see it using view page source.or use notepad++ to se it.